# VSCode does not detect import path from node_modules

Tags: visual-studio-code, node-modules

I have multiple packages installed, such as:

```
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
"@testing-library/react-hooks": "^7.0.2",
```

when I import like this (`*` is something exported from these libs):

```
import * from '@testing-library/jest-dom' // ok, vscode knows this and even auto imports
import * from '@testing-library/react' // vscode doesn't detect this
import * from '@testing-library/react-hooks' // vscode doesn't know what this is
```

I don't know why because they are added to `package.json` and installed normally. The code which uses these libraries works 100% fine. The problem is that VSCode cannot work with them, no path auto import, no suggestion, no reference...

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have installed correct libraries for it or not. If no try to install it or check again in case if you have not installed. If the problem still persists try re-downloading vs code

Comment: All the functions which are exported from these libs work fine. I've never got this problem until this project.